# Errno 14 PYCURL ERROR 22 The requested URL returned error 403 Forbidden

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

## yum update

http:///repo/rhel-x86_64-server-6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: rhel6_64. Please verify its path and try again

Comment: disable proxy
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy

yum clean all
yum upate

Comment: See the problem but are you implying in your comment that disabling proxies helped in your case ?

Answer (score 4):

Reason for this error:
1) You are behind a proxy server.
    To fix:
        a) unset http_proxy
        b) Remove any proxy entry made by you in /etc/yum.conf

2) open firefox and enter you password manually in the browser and run yum update in command line.

Answer (score 2):

[root@hostname tmp]# yum update

Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
http://hostname.org/mrepo/rhel6s-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"

[root@hostname tmp]# yum clean all

Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Cleaning repos: reponame
Cleaning up Everything

[root@hostname tmp]# yum update

Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
reponame                                                                                                                                                                   | 3.0 kB     00:00
usz/primary_db                                                                                                                                                        | 6.5 MB     00:00
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update

Comment: Why have you posted your answer twice?

Answer (score -1):

Check your proxy configuration.
Export http_proxy environment variable

And check this out: https://superuser.com/questions/767443/mirror-repository-wont-work-the-requested-url-returned-error-403-forbidden